# How to remove a section from the table of contents?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Or in other words: is there something like `\tocless` for Rmd's? I found something for Latex [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214137/137734), but could not find anything for an Rmd.

Changing toc-depth is not an option:

```
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
    toc_depth: 2
```

Reproducible example:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "SQC"
date: "7 Juni 2018"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
    toc_depth: 2
    theme: yeti
---

## Sec. 1

bla

## Sec. 2 - not part of content

bla
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though some years have passed since the post of this question, I still want to respond to this question because others may benefit from the answer. If you do not want certain section headings to be included in the table of contents, you can add two classes to the heading: unlisted and unnumbered. For example:

```
# Section heading {.unlisted .unnumbered}
```

See here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/toc-unlisted.html

Comment: Great, I did not notice that change :-)