# How can I use Latex' \newcommand in Rmd?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I would like to make the following work

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "SQC"
date: "21 September 2018"
output: html_document
---

\newcommand{\short}{AreallylongwordIhavetotypefrequently}

# My Test
I would like to write \short which does not work, $\short$ however is close... 
Snippets do not work in Rmd plain text (= Rstudio's "Shift", see link below).
```

But I could not find a solution. It would be great if there is something around!
The following links are helpful, but didn't suggest a solution: [pandoc doc](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html%23raw-tex#latex_macros), [\newcommand in Rmd formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41655383/5784831) and [RStudio snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37748516/5784831).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using R instead:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "SQC"
date: "21 September 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
short <- "AreallylongwordIhavetotypefrequently"
```

# My Test
I would like to write `r short` instead ...
````

Comment: Awesome - so simple!!

Comment: Perhaps you also know an answer for the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50740687/5784831)? ;-)

Comment: @Christoph Sorry, I have no idea how to solve that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to define a `\newcommand` using LaTeX in Rmarkdown, you can do so by e.g.

````
Some text with the following equation:

\begin{equation} \newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\matr{Y} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\matr{y_1} \\
\matr{y_2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

```{r}
y1 + y2
```
````

Note, the `bm` package must be loaded for this to work, e.g., by using this in the YAML header:

```
---
title: "My R Report" 
author: "Me" 
date: "2020-01-31" 
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{bm} 
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    toc: true 
    number_sections: true
---
```